# I just wanted to find where xdg-mime was looking for associations. What the hell is it _doing_?

Tags: xdg

It's too long to post the whole strace here, try

```
strace -fe open,openat xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

suffice to say that command spits 429 lines, it seems like it's attaching processes to read each file and other processes to do god knows what, dozens of processes in all.

Comment: It's a shell script.  Did you consider simply reading it?  Or using the shell's various facilities to debug what it executes?

Comment: @JdeBP gaahh. It never occured to me it'd be a shell script.  I'm officially designating today my brainless day, this wasn't the only symptom :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdg-mime` is a shell script, so you'll get a more manageable trace by asking the shell.

```
dash -x /usr/bin/xdg-mime
```

The first complex action after parsing the command line is to detect your desktop environment, using a combination of methods: environment variables, detecting the Gnome session manager through D-Bus, and querying properties of the root window. This is done so that e.g. you get to read PDF files in Evince on Gnome and Okular on KDE.

After that, `xdg-mime` looks for programs registered as XDG applications in locations that depend on the detected desktop environment.